# Zelle graphics in Python: How to move two objects separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

In this program I am able to get the green object to move but not the other one. I commented 'PROBLEM' above an 'if' statement written under function pygame()  where I believe the problem exists. Am I supposed to make an elif statement to get the other object to move? Break after if valid(r, c)? etc. Here is the code:

```
from graphics import *
from time import sleep

''''''
def main():
    global win,msg 
    win = GraphWin("PYGAME", winW, winH)
    msg = Text(Point(100, winH - off_field//2), "PYGAME")
    msg.draw(win)
    make_field()
    button_Exit, button_Restart = create_buttons()
    pygame() 

    win.getMouse()                 
    win.close()
''''''    

column, row = 12, 10             

adjacent = ( ( -1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1),
            ( -1,  0),          (1,  0),
            ( -1,  1), (0,  1), (1,  1) ) 

square_size = 30                   # Size of each square on the field
off_field = 100                    # Display off the field


# field : main game variable; 'I' = ice, 'B': broken
field = [ [ 'I' for c in range (column)] for r in range (row) ]


# user: identifies whose turn it is to play (click)
user = 0                  # How do I switch users?


# Initial users' positions: [r, c]; None later replaced by Circle
users = [ [ row//2, 0, None],
            [ row//2, column-1, None] ]     

winW, winH = column * square_size, row * square_size + off_field  # 360, 400

win = None              # main app window
msg = None              # main information Text
button_Exit = None         # exit button
button_Restart = None      # restart button

# squares: grid of squares, initially white, later changed to blue:
squares = None

''''''

# pygame_reset():  resets positions and squares turn white
def pygame_reset():
    global win, squares
    for r in range(row):
            for c in range(column):
                squares[r][c].setFill('white')


    users[0][:2] = [row//2, 0]
    users[1][:2] = [row//2, 0]

    # User 1 and 2 are repositioned

# make_field(): makes visual grid of squares
def make_field():
    global win, squares
    # Allocate memory space for Rectangle objects:
    squares = [ [ None for c in range (column)] for r in range (row) ]

    for r in range(row):
        for c in range(column):
            x, y = c * square_size, r * square_size 
            squares[r][c] = Rectangle(Point(x,y), Point(x + square_size, y + square_size) )
            squares[r][c].draw(win)



    users[0][2] = Circle(Point(square_size//2, square_size//2 + row //2 *square_size), 
                                                         square_size//2-5)
    users[0][2].setFill('green')
    users[0][2].draw(win)

    users[1][2] = Circle(Point(square_size*11.5, square_size//2 + row //2 *square_size), 
                                                           square_size//2-5)
    users[1][2].setFill('yellow')
    users[1][2].draw(win) 



    # Reset user's positions and all squares to white:
    pygame_reset()

# returns True if position (r, c) is adjacent to 
# current user's position
# Recall: users = [ [ r, c, Circle],[ r, c, Circle] ]
def valid(r, c):
    pr, pc = users[user][0:2]       

    for dc, dr in adjacent:
        if pr + dr == r and pc + dc == c:
            return True

    return False


def button_template(win, x, y, w, h, txt):

    r = Rectangle(Point(x, y), Point(x+w, y+h))
    r.setFill("white")
    r.draw(win)
    t = Text(r.getCenter(), txt) # same as Point(x+w//2, y+h//2)
    t.draw(win)
    return [ r, t ]


def create_buttons():
    global win, field, squares, msg

    button_Exit = button_template(win, 260, winH - off_field//1.25, 60, 25, "Exit")
    button_Restart = button_template(win, 260, winH - off_field//2.25, 60, 25, "Restart")

    return (button_Exit, button_Restart)


def temporary_color(r, c):              
    global squares
    color = squares[r][c].config['fill']
    squares[r][c].setFill('red')
    sleep(0.5)
    squares[r][c].setFill(color)

def move_user(r, c):
    global msg, user, users
    pr, pc = users[user][0:2]             
    dx, dy = square_size * (c - pc), square_size * (r - pr)

    users[user][2].move(dx, dy)
    users[user][0:2] = [ r, c]      
    msg.setText("User moves in: " + str((r, c)))


def pygame():
    global win, field, squares, msg
    while True:                         
        pt = win.getMouse()


        if pt.x > 260 and pt.y > winH - off_field//1.25:


                    msg.setText("Exit")
                    break        


        if pt.x > 260 and pt.y > winH - off_field//2.25:

                    msg.setText("Restart")       
                    break        

        if pt.y < row * square_size:          
            r, c = pt.y // square_size, pt.x // square_size  

            msg.setText(str((r, c)))  

            # PROBLEM - DO I USE 'break' SOMEWHERE HERE?
            if valid(r, c):

                move_user(r, c)

            # Do I use elif? Break? What to do next?

            else:
                temporary_color(r, c)
                msg.setText("Invalid move") 
                continue

            if valid(r, c):
                squares[r][c].setFill('orange')
                field[r][c] = 'B'

        else:             
            msg.setText("Not in field")



main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a more sophisticated loop for taking turns.  The loop has to keep accepting mouse input until a valid move is made, then switch users.  Here's a slightly streamlined version of your program with such a loop:

```
from time import sleep
from graphics import *

COLUMNS, ROWS = 12, 10

ADJACENT = (
    (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1),
    (-1,  0),          (1,  0),
    (-1,  1), (0,  1), (1,  1)
)

SQUARE_SIZE = 30  # Size of each square on the field
OFF_FIELD = 20  # Display off the field

WIN_W, WIN_H = COLUMNS * SQUARE_SIZE, ROWS * SQUARE_SIZE + OFF_FIELD

# pygame_reset():  resets positions and squares turn white
def pygame_reset():
    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLUMNS):
            squares[r][c].setFill('white')

    # User 1 and 2 are repositioned
    users[0][:2] = [ROWS // 2, 0]
    users[1][:2] = [ROWS // 2, COLUMNS - 1]

# make_field(): makes visual grid of squares
def make_field():
    for r in range(ROWS):
        y = r * SQUARE_SIZE

        for c in range(COLUMNS):
            x = c * SQUARE_SIZE
            squares[r][c] = Rectangle(Point(x, y), Point(x + SQUARE_SIZE, y + SQUARE_SIZE))
            squares[r][c].draw(win)

    users[0][2] = Circle(Point(SQUARE_SIZE//2, SQUARE_SIZE//2 + ROWS//2 * SQUARE_SIZE), SQUARE_SIZE//2 - 5)
    users[0][2].setFill('green')

    users[1][2] = Circle(Point(SQUARE_SIZE * 11.5, SQUARE_SIZE//2 + ROWS//2 * SQUARE_SIZE), SQUARE_SIZE//2 - 5)
    users[1][2].setFill('yellow')

    # Reset user's positions and all squares to white:
    pygame_reset()

    users[0][2].draw(win)
    users[1][2].draw(win)

# returns True if position (r, c) is adjacent to
# current user's position
# Recall: users = [[r, c, Circle], [r, c, Circle]]
def valid(r, c):
    pr, pc = users[user][:2]

    for dc, dr in ADJACENT:
        if pr + dr == r and pc + dc == c:
            return True

    return False

def temporary_color(r, c):
    color = squares[r][c].config['fill']
    squares[r][c].setFill('red')
    sleep(0.5)
    squares[r][c].setFill(color)

def move_user(r, c):
    pr, pc = users[user][:2]
    dx, dy = SQUARE_SIZE * (c - pc), SQUARE_SIZE * (r - pr)

    users[user][2].move(dx, dy)
    users[user][:2] = r, c
    msg.setText("User {} moves to: {}".format(user, (r, c)))

    squares[r][c].setFill('orange')
    field[r][c] = 'B'

def pygame():
    global user

    while True:
        finished_move = False

        while not finished_move:
            pt = win.getMouse()

            if pt.y < ROWS * SQUARE_SIZE:
                r, c = int(pt.y // SQUARE_SIZE), int(pt.x // SQUARE_SIZE)

                if valid(r, c):
                    move_user(r, c)
                    finished_move = True
                else:
                    temporary_color(r, c)
                    msg.setText("Invalid move for user {}".format(user))
            else:
                msg.setText("Not in field")

        user = 1 - user  # switch user

# field : main game variable; 'I' = ice, 'B': broken
field = [['I' for c in range(COLUMNS)] for r in range(ROWS)]

# squares: grid of squares, initially white, later changed to blue:
squares = [[None for c in range(COLUMNS)] for r in range(ROWS)]

# user: identifies whose turn it is to play (click)
user = 0  # How do I switch users?

# Initial users' positions: [r, c]; None later replaced by Circle
users = [
    [ROWS // 2, 0, None],
    [ROWS // 2, COLUMNS - 1, None]
]

win = GraphWin("PYGAME", WIN_W, WIN_H)  # main app window
msg = Text(Point(WIN_W//2, WIN_H - OFF_FIELD//2), "PYGAME")  # main information Text
msg.draw(win)

make_field()
pygame()

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

[image]

Code-wise, you need to (re)read about the `global` statement and when it's used.